# Outlook email and my ip address

Tags: web-application, email

If I send someone an email using Outlook online, can the recipient know my IP?
I knew before that it was possible but I was wondering if the email providers like Outlook, Gmail had added some sort of security for that?

Comment: Why are you worried about someone knowing your IP address?

Comment: When using a webclient, the IP of the device accessing the webclient is not part of the email sending process, so your IP is not passed on.

Answer (score 0):

An e-mail is nothing but text conforming to the **SMTP** (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol). When accessed through a web client, it appears formatted, but the its **source** (underlying raw text) can be displayed (in Outlook Web you can click on the three dots on the right side of an e-mail message and then on `View message source`).

One of the headers present in the source is the *Received* header, which says where the e-mail was received from. In theory, this could be your personal IP (or domain, if applicable). However, close inspection of the message source will reveal that with most e-mail sending services (Outlook Web itself for example), the Received headers only mention Microsoft server IPs.

If you were to send it *yourself* however (e.g. by opening a Telnet session to an Outlook SMTP server and sending an e-mail), your IP would indeed be visible by viewing the message source.